# Why does getNdefMessage() returns null even though debugger shows ndef object has a message payload that is supposedly correctly formatted?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am trying to continuously poll an NFC tag using an android phone (OnePlus 6T if it's relevant). When my tag is only powered by NFC, I get null values even though the debugger shows the payload being not null and supposedly correctly formatted (screenshot below).

**Debugger output when getNdefMessage returns null**

[image: Debugger output when getNdefMessage returns null]

**Debugger output when the returned value is not null**

[image: Debugger output when the returned value is not null]

The code I am using to poll the tag, based on [Continuously detect an NFC tag on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045486/continuously-detect-an-nfc-tag-on-android) and [Is it possible to read an NFC tag from a card without using an intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825924/is-it-possible-to-read-an-nfc-tag-from-a-card-without-using-an-intent)

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (nfcAdapter != null) {
        if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        Bundle options = new Bundle();

        options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);

        nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
                        Log.d("Tag", "New tag detected, attempting connect");
                        readMessage(tag);
                        tagInRange = true;
                    }
                },
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A
                        | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS, options);

    }
}
```

Read message function, `msg` variable is a `private volatile NdefMessage`:

```
private void readMessage(Tag tag) {
    Log.d("Tag", "Starting thread");
    new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1800);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        Log.d("Tag", "New tag detected, attempting connect");

        while (tagInRange) {

            try {
                ndef.connect();
                msg = ndef.getNdefMessage();

                Log.d("Tag", "Running on UI thread");
                if (msg == null) {
                    Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(ndef));
                    continue;
                }
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    parseMessage(msg);
                    dataElapsedTime += 0.2;
                });

            } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tagInRange = false;
                System.out.println("Tag Connection Lost");
            }

            finally {

                try {
                    ndef.close();
                    Log.d("tag", "Tag connection closed successfully");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        }

    }).start();

}
```

Does the getNdefMessage function use some sort of lazy loading? Or is this the result of multiple threads being spawned and some strange race condition occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was finally resolved by understanding the following things:

1. The mNdefmessage variable in the ndef object corresponds to the cached message and would remain unchanged as long as the same tag instance is connected. I was reading the object wrong and presuming that that is the message I want. Thanks to Andrew for pointing this out!
2. The null I was receiving was not a result of where the connect/close were called and the android code needed minimal changes from what was initially posted. In the documentation for the function `getNdefMessage()`, it says, function may return null if tag is initialised stage. This turned out to be the real issue, which was only spotted when I set my tag (NHS3152) to blink an LED when starting up and noticed it was restarting several times after taking a set of readings from a connected resistor which shouldn't be happening (this also led to a lot of tag lost/null object exceptions).
3. Since the documentation on this is scanty, the reason the tag was restarting/reset turned out to be its inability to handle voltages over a certain threshold on its output pins when powered by the NFC field only and connected to a load. This led to the strange scenario of everything working just fine when the tag was being read while connected to a debugging board (LPCLink2) or being powered by the NFC but not connected to a load. This was finally addressed by changing the output voltage on the DAC pin.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

Looking at the source of the [ndef object](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/core/java/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.java#184) the `mNdefMsg` you highlighted is the cached Ndef message that the System Reads before passing you the Tag object

As you seem have a custom behaving tag and may be this tag won't allow you to read the same data twice without going through a disconnect/connect mechanism.

Based on you debug data I would use `ndef.getCachedNdefMessage()` to read this data you are highlighting but this might not get you want you want.

Some Background, when the Android NFC service detects a Tag normally it tries to read and Ndef message from it as it might need to parse the Ndef message itself.

When you call `ndef.getNdefMessage()` it actually re-reads the data directly from the Tag and ignores what the System NFC service has previous read.

I would try enabling `FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK` to stop the system reading the Ndef Message and using up you one chance to read the custom Tag .

So try add that flag e.g.

```java
nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
                        Log.d("Tag", "New tag detected, attempting connect");
                        readMessage(tag);
                        tagInRange = true;
                    }
                },
                NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A
                        | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK
                        | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS, options);
```

**Original**

I think the problem is your `ndef.close()` is in the wrong place.

You should not close the tag unless you never want to communicate with it again.

At the moment on the first iteration of the while loop, it does the try block with the `ndef.connect();` and the `finally` is always executed after the code in the preceding try block.

Really you should only `ndef.close()`  outside the while block.

Adjusted code (You should also catch the `TagLostException` from `getNdefMessage` )

```java
private void readMessage(Tag tag) {
    Log.d("Tag", "Starting thread");
    new Thread(() -> {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1800);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        Log.d("Tag", "New tag detected, attempting connect");
    
        try { 
          ndef.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tagInRange = false;
                System.out.println("Failed to Connect");
        }

        while (tagInRange) {

            try {
                msg = ndef.getNdefMessage();

                Log.d("Tag", "Running on UI thread");
                if (msg == null) {
                    Log.d("Tag", String.valueOf(ndef));
                    continue;
                }
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    parseMessage(msg);
                    dataElapsedTime += 0.2;
                });

            } catch (TagLostException | IOException | FormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tagInRange = false;
                System.out.println("Tag Connection Lost");
            }
        }
        
        // End of while loop try close just on the safe side
        
        try {
                    ndef.close();
                    Log.d("tag", "Tag connection closed successfully");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }).start();

}
```

Note you might think the raw tag debug output still has an Ndef Message in it, but as you have not disabled `FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK` then this is probably the cached data for `ndef.getCachedNdefMessage()`

If you look at the docs for [ndef.getCachedNdefMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef#getCachedNdefMessage()) you will see that it says that it causes no RF activity as this just returns the NDEF message that the System NFC read when it first detected the Tag and passed to you in the Tag Object.

Where as `getNdefMessage` cause I/O (RF) activity and reads the **current** Ndef message at time of calling (which might be different to the one the system read previously)

**Update**

I seem to remember you cannot call `connect()` multiple times and and the docs say "Only one TagTechnology object can be connected to a Tag at a time. " even though it is the same Tag tech it is probably not the same instance, so in the example I've moved connect out of the while loop.

Comment: I had tried that but it also happens on the very first read. I see a NDefMessage in the ndef object but the get function returns null. Is ```getCachedNdefMessage``` a fallback for getNdefMessage? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: `getCachedNdefMessage` is a side effect of how Tags are handled in Android and is documented at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef#getCachedNdefMessage() . When Android detects a Tag the System NFC service reads any Ndef message if there is one, because the system might action the Ndef message itself e.g. open a web browser if the Ndef message is a URL. It then passes this message in the Tag object it the App that requested to be notified that an NFC Tag has come in to range. With `enableReaderMode` you can disable this pre read with `FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK`

Comment: I don't know if creating your own thread is complicating things and is not really needed, `OnTagDiscovered` is already in it's own Thread and therefore you could sleep the current Thread with `Thread.sleep(1800);` in `OnTagDiscovered`

Comment: I tried this as well by removing the ```new Thread``` code block and simplifying the function. I still get the ```null``` in the ```msg``` variable but not in the ndef payload (which also changes on consecutive reads)

Comment: Updated, I don't think you can call `connect` multiple times, so moved that out of the while loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045486/continuously-detect-an-nfc-tag-on-android - calling it multiple times and disconnecting after each time seems okay. I tried stepping through with the debugger as well and it seems that ```NdefMessage msg = tagService.ndefRead(serviceHandle);``` in the getNdefMessage returns null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240583/discussion-between-aayush-chadha-and-andrew).